# Convert float to integer simplifies data ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, integer

My student is having a problem when he tries to convert floating raster data to integer: the data is simplified and produces a considerably different map.

Any ideas for setting conditions or re-doing the raster calculator equation to sidestep this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There isn't enough information on the range of values before and after, but generally multiplying the float by an order of magnitude or two is able to preserve some fidelity (e.g., `iraster = int(fraster * 100)`), though performance will degrade if the pixel depth is compromised.

Comment: If you simply convert original to integer, resulting raster will hold 4 unique numbers. Output shows 4 colors, so it is expected result.

Comment: To compliment the others if your student is just feeding their raster into the int() tool they are essentially rounding to nearest whole number. You need to do what @Vince suggests, multiply the raster by 100 to shift decimal point two places to the right then feed that into the int() tool. So your raster will be INTEGER but in the thousands, you do your processing and remember to divide by 100 to get back to the original cell value.

Comment: Note that dividing by 100.0 won't get the original cell value, just something close (within 0.005, if rounding occurred; within 0.01 otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

There is most of the time a loss of information when you convert float to integers. I would say that there are two types of solution to avoid losing too much :

1. rescale the data by multiplying the raster values by a constant (e.g. 1000). In this case, think about the type of integer before you rescale (Byte goes up to 255, uint16 up to 65535 etc). the "optimal" linear rescaling will use the maximum and the minimum values of your dataset: 255 * (rastervalue - min )/ (max - min)
2. reclassify the data into meaningfull group. You will then loose the quantitative information and replace it with categories. e.g. "0 to 3" becomes "small" (stored as 1), ...,  and "100 to 1000" becomes "large" (stored as 5).